# JPA: redundant sql insertions after using multiple many-to-many relations between three entities

Tags: java, entity-framework, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I have User, Role and Permission entities and use embedded db for development purpose. User and Role have many-to-many relation and, also, Role and Permission have many-to-many relation too:
1) User entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "usr")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class User implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 818129969599480161L;
    /**
     * Unique id for the User. "@Id" declare the parameter as the primary key
     * "@GeneratedValue" indicates JPA 2 (and behind Hibernate) which strategy
     * to use for creating a new value.
     * "GenerationType.AUTO" value allow JPA implementation to use the better way depending to the RDBMS used.
     */
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    /**
     * Login of the user. No annotation here, the parameter will be automatically mapped in the table.
     */
    private String login;
    /**
     * Password of the user. No annotation here, the parameter will be automatically mapped in the table.
     */
    private String password;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "USER_ROLES",
            joinColumns =
            @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns =
            @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();
.....(getters and setters)
```

2) Role entity:

```
@Entity
public class Role {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    private String roleName;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<User> users = new HashSet<>();

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "ROLE_PERMISSION",
            joinColumns =
            @JoinColumn(name = "ROLE_ID"),
            inverseJoinColumns =
            @JoinColumn(name = "PERMISSION_ID"))
    private Set<Permission> permissions = new HashSet<>();
    .....(getters and setters)
```

3) Permisson entity:

```
    @Entity
    public class Permission {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        private int id;
        private String permissionName;

        @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "permissions", fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {})
        private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();
    .....(getters and setters)
```

And offcause my test populator:

```
public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
    _logger.debug("setting test uses data");

    Permission permission = new Permission();
    permission.setPermissionName("PERM_SAVE_PRODUCT");

    permissionRepository.save(permission);

    Role role = new Role();
    role.setRoleName("ROLE_ADMIN");
    Set<Permission> permissions = new HashSet<>();
    permissions.add(permission);
    role.setPermissions(permissions);

    roleRepository.save(role);

    User user = new User();
    user.setLogin("dmitro");
    user.setPassword("2424");
    user.setStatus(UserStatus.ACTIVE);
    Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<Role>();
    roles.add(role);
    user.setRoles(roles);

    userRepository.save(user);
}
```

I expected that **one** user record, **one** role record and **one** permission record are created and inserted into particulars repos.
All seems to be clean (without any exception) but rest clien show me that I have **two** role records and **three** permission records, for role for example:

```
{
"links": [
],
"content": [
    {
        "links": [
            {
                "rel": "roles.Role.permissions",
                "href": "http://localhost:8080/admin/roles/1/permissions"
            },
            {
                "rel": "self",
                "href": "http://localhost:8080/admin/roles/1"
            },
            {
                "rel": "roles.Role.users",
                "href": "http://localhost:8080/admin/roles/1/users"
            }
        ],
        "roleName": "ROLE_ADMIN"
    },
    {
        "links": [
            {
                "rel": "roles.Role.permissions",
                "href": "http://localhost:8080/admin/roles/2/permissions"
            },
            {
                "rel": "self",
                "href": "http://localhost:8080/admin/roles/2"
            },
            {
                "rel": "roles.Role.users",
                "href": "http://localhost:8080/admin/roles/2/users"
            }
        ],
        "roleName": "ROLE_ADMIN"
    }
],
"page": {
    "size": 20,
    "totalElements": 2,
    "totalPages": 1,
    "number": 1
}
```

}

In log I see that it is all created but why in such way I do not know yet, please help. **log** is here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/orx3c9p023bxmti/log.txt?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are saving user ,Role , permission separately . This will result multiple records . Since you have given **Cascade All** saving User Object will save role objects and permission objects too.

try like this

```
public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
_logger.debug("setting test uses data");

User user = new User();
user.setLogin("dmitro");
user.setPassword("2424");
user.setStatus(UserStatus.ACTIVE);
Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<Role>();
Role role = new Role();
role.setRoleName("ROLE_ADMIN");
Set<Permission> permissions = new HashSet<>();
Permission permission = new Permission();
permission.setPermissionName("PERM_SAVE_PRODUCT");
permissions.add(permission);
role.setPermissions(permissions);
roles.add(role);
user.setRoles(roles);
userRepository.save(user);
```

}

See about cascade [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/example-parentchild.html) .  Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you a lot!, a documentation and code snippet given by you are resolved my question